# How do I get the state of a background operation (Quartz job?) in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to accomplish triggering a quartz job and somehow bind that job to a specific user or session and have the ability to check the status of the job.

Basically I need to trigger a job every time a user logs in. This job downloads information specific to that user -- it could take several minutes, and many of these jobs could be triggered async'ly for multiple users logging in at the same time.

Now the thing is, while the job is running, the user could be visiting different pages on the site -- that is, I don't want to interrupt them, so I need a way to trigger the job, but first check if there is already one running for that specific user. I also need the ability to update the UI once the job is finished.

I'm sort of at a loss here.. I can't find much on Google so I would really appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Executor Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/executor).  It adds a `callAsync()` MetaMethod to your Grails artefacts, which will return a Java `Future` object, so that you can retrieve the status and results of your async call.

If you need Quartz's scheduling ability as well, just put your logic in a Grails Service and call the Service method from the Quartz job or via `callAsync()` depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, checking it out. What can I do with the Future object if I have to check the status via ajax -- I have to check the status across multiple requests while callAsync runs in the background.

Comment: You could try storing it in a standard location in the session and checking for its existence and the status of its `isDone()` method to determine the progress of your job.

Answer (score 0):

I can only offer a suggestion. I'm not sure why you're asking how to trigger a job every time a user logs. For this, all you need to do is put all the code in the job into a service so that in the login controller you can also call the service code when the user logs in.

In the job class:

```
class EmailAlertJob {

    def utilService
    static triggers = {
       cron name: 'emailCronTrigger', cronExpression: "0 15 1 ? * SUN-SAT"
    }
    def execute() {
       def send= utilService.sendEmail()
    }
}
```

In the controller:

```
def userLogsIn = {
    utilService.sendEmail()
}
```

As far as keeping track if the job is running, there are several ways to do this such as keep a flag specific to the user, and checking the flag before running the job.